# AD sync issue for Project server 2010

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, project-server

> A resource could not be updated during Project Server Active Directory
>   Synchronization because a duplicate windows account name conflict
>   occured that could not be resolved. Resource GUID:
>   xxxxxxx-xxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx. Resource Name xxx xxxx. Windows Account:

I saw the list of users after the sync and the error was with few users and they are not available in that list *MSP_Resources table*

Comment: as it saying, try to find "because a duplicate windows account name conflict:

Answer (score 0):

Below link might be helpful for your issue:

http://patrickdrews.com/2012/12/project-server-active-directory-synchronization-error-event-7734/

Comment: Any Projects owned by Resources you delete will be assigned to your account  
You cannot delete Resources and Users that are currently checked out to other users. In order to forcibly check them in, go to this page: Force Check-in Enterprise Objects

Comment: so with this process i should reassign many users to time sheets and the projects so that would not be a right solution